# PyFlink reading Parquet files

Tags: parquet, pyflink

I'm happily reading text files via `env.read_text_file(file_path)`, but how can I read a parquet file in PyFlink?

I'm aware of
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/dataset/formats/parquet/ for Java/Scala ...but is is possible with the Python version to somehow include the flink-parquet__2.11 dependency, and then have a FileSource with the parquetInputFormat?